# What is the difference between $f(x)=x^2 +1$ and $f(x)=x^3 -1$ when finding the inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

I'm doing some exercises on computing the inverse of each function.

In exercise number 56 I did an example where I have to compute the inverse of the function. With my understanding $f(x)=x^2 +1$ inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x-1}$. The Solutions Book says $f^{-1}(x)$ does not exist.

On exercise 60 I got almost the same concept to get the inverse. $f(x)=x^3-1$ which my answer is $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$. The solutions Book says $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$ which I was right.

My question is why is exercise 56 inverse of function does not exist and on exercise 60 it does?

Comment: Because your $f$ is not injective. The function $f'$ you write (not a good name, given that usually $f'$ refers to the derivative of $f$) is only the inverse of the restriction of $f$ to the interval from $0$ to $+\infty$

Answer (score 3):

The solutions of $y=x^2+1$ are $x=\sqrt{y-1}$ and $x=-\sqrt{y-1}$. There are two solutions, this function is not [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), there is no unique solution $x$ given $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

To solve for the inverse of $f(x) = x^3 - 1$, we set $y = x^3 - 1$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.
\begin{align*}
y & = x^3 - 1\\
y + 1 & = x^3\\
\sqrt[3]{y + 1} & = x
\end{align*}
Since each real number has a unique cube root, $x$ is uniquely determined by the value of $y$.  Hence, $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3]{x + 1}$ exists.

If we attempt to do the same thing with the function $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
y & = x^2 + 1\\
y - 1 & = x^2\\
\sqrt{y - 1} & = |x| && \text{since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$}\\
\pm \sqrt{y - 1} & = x
\end{align*}
For each $y > 1$, there are two values of $x$ such that $y = x^2 + 1$.  Hence, $x$ is not uniquely determined by $y$.  Thus, the equation $x = \pm \sqrt{y - 1}$ does not define a function, so the inverse of $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ does not exist.

Remember that if $f$ is a function of $x$, there is a unique $y$-value for each $x$-value in the domain.  This means that a vertical line will cross the graph of a function at most once, which is known as the *Vertical Line Test*.

A function has an inverse if in addition to being able to express $y$ as a function of $x$, we can write $x$ as a function of $y$.  For this to occur, not only must there be a unique value of $y$ for each value of $x$, there must be a unique value of $x$ for each value of $y$.  This means that a horizontal line will cross the graph of a function at most once, which is known as the *Horizontal Line Test*.

Observe that for each value of $y > 1$, a horizontal line crosses the graph of $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ twice, so $x$ is not uniquely determined by $y$ if $y > 1$.  On the other hand, for each value of $y$, a horizontal line crosses the graph of $f(x) = x^3 - 1$ once, so $x$ is uniquely determined by $y$ for each value of $x$.

[image: horizontal_line_test_for_inverse]

Observe that for each $x > 1$, a vertical line crosses the graph of $y = \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ twice, so the equation $y = \pm\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ does not represent the graph of a function.  On the other hand, for any value of $x$, a vertical line crosses the graph of $y = x^3 - 1$ exactly once, so its graph does represent a function.

[image: vertical_line_test_for_proposed_inverse_functions]

Comment: Great answer.I admire your effort to write it all down.+1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graph of $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ (green) and the inverted graph (blue, light blue).
The inverted graph is a relation but no function, because it assigns more than one value for each argument $x$ with $x > 1$. So there is no inverse function.

[image: First graph and inverse]

And here is the graph of $f(x) = x^3 - 1$ (green) and the inverted graph (blue).
In this case the inverted graph is a function and the inverse function exists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think what happens e.g. at the point $x=-3$ for the 1st function and the 1st inverse function. That's what the book means. The 1st function is not reversible when viewed over the whole real line.